# Online tool for making Geometric Constructions.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

There was a website where it tasked you making different geometric shapes using only a compass and straightedge.

I've looked for it and I can't find it or even discussion about it. What I do remember is talk that it might be taken down, but it'd be nice to at least find that discussion. Any help on the project's name or its URL?

Comment: [Euclid: The Game](http://euclidthegame.com), perhaps?

Comment: [Geogebra online](https://www.geogebra.org/material/show/id/124609)

Answer (score 1):

http://sciencevsmagic.net/geo/ maybe? It's a puzzle similar to Euclid: The Game. I first saw this about a year ago, so I don't know anything about its developments.